# How to close CSS only dropdown menu after click any link in dropdown?

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am developing a React Website, where I have a navigation menu with 2 dropdowns. On desktop, the Dropdowns are showing after hovering in the parent menu. There I used only CSS hover to show the dropdown. When I click any link from the dropdown page is changing but the dropdown is not close after a click. Is there any solution using CSS to dropdown after a click on its link?

**My CSS code is like this to show the dropdown:**

```
.subMenu{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 140px;  
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.hasSubmenu:hover .subMenu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 80px;
}
```

**I have something like this to close dropdown:**

```
.subMenu:active {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Please check my screenshot:**
[image: dropdown screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a JavaScript Event Listener to `ul` of submenu and whenever you click you could do something like

```
let ulList=document.querySelector('.submenu')
let ulElements=document.querySelector('.submenu--items')
ulList.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  ulElements.style.visibility="hidden";
})
```

Since you haven't attached HTML code it's hard to understand this snippet but,
this should probably do the trick.....